# Как при включении ПК сделать выбор между Ubuntu/Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Установил как вторую операционную Ubuntu. При включении ПК по-умолчанию открывается Windows, чтобы открыть Ubuntu необходим заходить в BIOS Boot Manager и там выбирать Ubuntu. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при включении ПК был выбор между OS?

Comment: Если у вас Windows XP/7, советую прочитать [данную статью](https://kzncomputer.ru/articles/45-kak-vkluchit-vibor-operacionnoy-sistemy). Если у вас Windows 10, [эту](https://www.cherneenet.ru/kak-sdelat-vybor-zagruzki-sistemy-v-windows.html).

Comment: Можно выхлоп `blkid` и `fdisk -l`?

Comment: Можно подробнее про *"заходить в BIOS Boot Manager и там выбирать Ubuntu"*?

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Для этого надо проверить, поставлен-ли os-prober (`ls -lah /etc/grub.d/*os-prober*`). Проверить, что ESP смонтирован в систему (`lsblk|grep "/boot/efi"`) ну и переустановить GRUB `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB` Обязательно убедиться что на этом этапе установщик не выдал ошибок, после чего перегенерить конфигурацию GRUB: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` Во время перезагрузки выбрать убунту, после чего в меню GRUB должен появиться пункт с виндой.

Answer (score 1):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Answer (score 1):

**Включение выбора операционной системы в Windows XP/7:**

- Нажимаем правой кнопкой мыши на значке "Мой компьютер" и в меню
- выбираем пункт "Свойства" В открывшемся окне "Система" найти
  слева ссылку "Дополнительные параметры системы" и нажать на нее
- В открывшемся окне "Свойства системы" требуется перейти на вкладку
  "Дополнительно"
- В разделе "Загрузка и восстановление" нажимаем
  кнопку "Параметры"
- Выбрать систему по умолчанию и нажать галочку "Отображать список операционных систем"

[Источник](https://kzncomputer.ru/articles/45-kak-vkluchit-vibor-operacionnoy-sistemy)